# Set Rails flash notice to appear on a day of the week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I get a specific flash notice to always appear in Ruby on Rails to appear if it's a Monday?

Comment: Check to see if it's Monday and if it is, put it in flash? Like in a system-wide `before_filter`? It's unclear if you want the message to appear only once, in which case you'd need to track that per-(user?).

Comment: Always show it if the day is a Monday.

Comment: How are you going to know what timezone the user is in?

Comment: I would say that you use javascript (jQuery perhaps) so the logic runs on the client side, that way will be easier to take into account the user's timezone just as @JohnNaegle mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :show_message_if_today_is_monday

  # rest of your ApplicationController code

private

  def show_message_if_today_is_monday
    flash[:notice] = "Your message here" if Time.now.monday?
  end
end
```

Comment: But `Time.now` will be the server time, what if the user has a 4 or 5 hours difference?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a notification model in your database that is polymorphic to a datetime. In this model, you could have four fields,

```
source_type: date, time and/or date & time
source_trigger: value of the source type
notification_message: message that you want to display
notification_styling: css styling
```

In your application controller, you can call to a helper method that can determine if the record in the notification model should appear. This way you can use it if you need to display a Tuesday message, 12:00PM message or a message at a date and time.

In your application layout, you can call for this notification instance variable to display the message notification.